# Why os.environ['PYTHONUNBUFFERED'] = 'x' is not flushing prints?

Tags: python, flush

`python --help` returns:

```
-u     : force the stdout and stderr streams to be unbuffered;
         this option has no effect on stdin; also PYTHONUNBUFFERED=x
```

So I put on start of my `main.py`:

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    os.environ['PYTHONUNBUFFERED'] = 'x'
```

Why my prints are not being flushed?

The behavior is different when I use `python -u main.py`. This second situation flush every single print, even the ones inside packages, and tha'ts what I want.

Comment: I suspect that the variable is only checked once during startup, so setting it from within the program is too late.

Comment: I think that it is not a good idea to change value in os.environ by python, you should do it by bash

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/107705/disable-output-buffering btw, first link when searching for PYTHONUNBUFFERED.

Comment: @WaketZheng what's the consequences of doing that? How Am I supposed to do it by bash

Comment: @UlrichEckhardt I saw this link but the focus of the answers follow another approach, so I maded this question to know how to make it unbuffered this way